# How to not serialize values which are initialized in a POJO?

Tags: java, jackson

If I have a POJO

```
class Night {

    int stars = 10;
    // getter and setter for stars
}
```

and i serialize it with Jackson it will serialize the `stars` field. But because the field is set like that when the object is created, there is no need to serialize the field unless the value is different than `10`.

I initially thought that `@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_DEFAULT)` does that but then realized that the "default" is with respect to the type, so 0 for int, and not with respect to the POJO.

I don't want to serialize a lot of values which don't need to be set when deserializing because that will happen anyway. I only want to serialize values that changed. Except for creating a custom serializer is there a way to do this?

I'm using Jackson 2.13 i think it's the latest.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your explanation of what you are trying to achieve, and am wondering whether you've used the word 'serialize' in places where you mean 'deserialize'. 

Can you provide clear scenarios showing exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Deserialize everything.  Your deserialized data should not be a combination of "deserialized values" and "values known only in code"; it should be all the fields. You won't be able to tell the difference between a default value and a missing value (though you can serialize nulls for non-primitive fields to indicate missing). Also, if your default value changes in the future your deserialized data will be incomplete/incorrect. I cannot think of any reason to conditionally skip deserialization; doing so will lead to regrets. Finally, I think you've used "serialize" and "deserialize" correctly.

Comment: @Paul "if your default value changes in the future your deserialized data will be incomplete/incorrect." that's a good point, I will consider it too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want jackson to write the `stars` field only when it is not equal to the default of 10, correct?

According to the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT), `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)` does exactly this when specified at the class level:

> public static final JsonInclude.Include NON_DEFAULT
>
> Meaning of this setting depends on context: whether annotation is specified for POJO type (class), or not. In latter case annotation is either used as the global default, or as property override.
>
> When used for a POJO, definition is that only values that differ from the default values of POJO properties are included. This is done by creating an instance of POJO using zero-argument constructor, and accessing property values: value is used as the default value by using equals() method, except for the case where property has `null` value in which case straight null check is used.
>
> When NOT used for a POJO (that is, as a global default, or as property override), definition is such that:
>
> - All values considered "empty" (as per NON_EMPTY) are excluded
> - Primitive/wrapper default values are excluded
> - Date/time values that have timestamp (`long` value of milliseconds since epoch, see Date) of `0L` are excluded

Basically, when serializing a POJO, it constructs a default object using the NoArgsConstructor, compares the fields to the ones generated by the default constructor, and doesn't include fields matching the default constructor.

I just tried it myself, (in Jackson 2.12.4), and the annotation only includes values that differ from the defaults set in the object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class TestClass { 
    private long id = 10;
    private long id2 = 10;
    private String name = "Fred";
    private String name2 = "Fred";
}
```

```
public class TestClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestClass temp1 = new TestClass();
        temp1.setId(5);
        temp1.setName2("Jeff");
        String json = json.writeValueAsString(temp1);
        ...
    }
}
```

This produces the following Json with only non-default values:
`{"id":5,"name2":"Jeff"}`
When mapped back into an object with `mapper.readValue(json, TestClass.class);`, this produces a TestClass object with the following fields:
`id=5, id2=10, name="Fred", name2="Jeff"`

**Important Note**: relying on serializing like this can have drawbacks, as Paul pointed out in the comments. You effectively cannot tell the difference between the default value of 10, and the field missing entirely, as both map to the same output. Also, your other microservices and applications will also need to have the same value for their defaults. This creates a code maintainability issue, as any changes to the default in one microservice will also have to be reflected in the other microservices and any other downstream application, with no good way to enforce a consistent default.

If you can, I would recommend mapping whatever actual defaults you have to the regular json defaults, such as 0 or null. But `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)` will work for other defaults too.

Comment: I just copy-pasted and tested your code and the JSON i get is `{"id":5,"id2":10,"name":"Fred","name2":"Jeff"}
`, which is different from yours. No idea why, maybe Jackson 2.12.4 is different than 2.13? Also you have a typo `json.writeValueAsString` should be `mapper.writeValueAsString` but that is trivial. if I change `private long id2 = 0;` in the class then `id2` is not serialized so it does what I described in the question.

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps there is some subtle difference in version, or perhaps some environment variable has been set and forgotten about that's changing it's behavior. I'll have to look into it more closely sometime soon. Sorry this isn't working for you at the moment.